# Prove $\lim_{x \to a} \cos{x} = \cos{a}$ using a $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ argument

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

> Prove $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \cos{x} = \cos{a}$ with $\varepsilon$-$\delta$.

Is proving $|\cos{x}-\cos{a}| \leq |x-a|$ with MVT the only way possible?

Comment: I’d like to point out that the question in the title and the question in the body of the post are different. One is asking for direction with a solution, and the other is asking if an alternative solution exists. Please make an edit so that they ask the same question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Use $$\cos(x) - \cos(a) = -2\sin\left(\frac{x+a}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-a}{2}\right)$$

Comment: got it thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given and suppose $\delta = \varepsilon$. Let $x$ satisfy $0<|x−a| < \delta$, then

\begin{align}|\cos x-\cos a|&=\left|-2\sin\left(\frac{x+a}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-a}{2}\right) \right|\\&= 2\left|\sin\left(\frac{x+a}{2}\right)\right|\cdot\left|\sin\left(\frac{x-a}{2}\right)\right|\\&\le 
2\left|\frac{x-a}{2}\right|.
\end{align}

Now conclude.

Comment: got it! thank you!

Comment: How do you get |$\sin(\frac{x-a}{2})\sin(\frac{x+a}{2})|\leq |\frac{x-a}{2}|$ ?

Comment: Since $|\sin(z)| \le |z|$ for all real $z$ we have $$\left|\sin\left(\frac{x-a}{2}\right)\right|\le \left|\frac{x-a}{2}\right|.$$ The other bound follows from $|\sin(w)| \le 1$ for all real $w$.